# How to customize my front page with background image?

Tags: 7

I have site for which I need to design a custom front page using my sub-theme with page page--front.tpl.php.

I need to place a background image and on title at left alignment and little bottom thre image background buttons and in that bottom center need to place on caret with hyperlink which will take you to rest of the half page.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try eiher of hese searches:

- Specific to [sub-theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=background+is%3Aq+%5B7%5D+sub-theme) topics.
- Specific to [front.tpl.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20%5B7%5D%20front.tpl.php).

Pick any of the proposed answers that fits best your needs. Such as a solution that is based on using something like firebug to find the CSS file that allows you to adapt your background to fit your needs.